Next.js 14.2.0 freshly created app throws ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME error when navigating to localhost:3000
This is my error after running npx create-next-app@latest:
Failed to compile

Next.js (14.2.0)
src\app\layout.js
An error occurred in `next/font`.

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'
    at throwIfUnsupportedURLScheme (node:internal/modules/esm/load:236:11)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:128:3)
    at ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:409:13)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:291:56)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:65:26)
    at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:303:17)
    at ModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:260:34)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:241:17)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:328:23)

I tried to fix it by running npx @next/codemod built-in-next-font. It didn't solve the error. How do I fix it?

The error is related to Next.js v14.2.0. There are two options to solve the error.

OPTION 1: Temporary solution until a new Next.js version is released (source)
Rename postcss.config.mjs to postcss.config.cjs.
Then change the export from this...
export default config;

...to this.
module.exports = config;


OPTION 2: Downgrade Next.js to v14.1.0
Downgrading should also solve the error.

Next-js update to version 14.2.0 that make me get error if anyone get the same error like me try to npx create-next-app@14.1.0 it's last version. for me it can run normally.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I build successfully 14.2 version without any error.
Only error in turbo mode

You probably didn't enable Tailwind CSS, or did you? It seems like if you don't enable Tailwind CSS, v14.2.0 works as expected.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
